Azure VM login failing through Entra ID error
Unable to access Azure VM using almost all Entra IDs apart from one. I have tried multiple Entra IDs with same administrative access and roles but somehow only 1 ID works.
The issue isn't due to MFA or NLA as I've already fixed those issues by disabling both of them.
The only key difference I can find is that that particular Entra ID is present in other Users as following:
(https://i.sstatic.net/CbdTRSAr.png)
I can't add the other Entra IDs as it states that account couldn't be found.
(https://i.sstatic.net/cp57HOgY.png)
I've also tried to use a method I found online where I ran the following command to add the user account:
net localgroup "Remote Desktop Users" /add "AzureAD\kanwar2@sandhullp.com"

And I can now see the users present in the remote access user list as follows, but I still get the same error while logging in:
(https://i.sstatic.net/CSgzsyrk.png)
Additional Info:
In the virtual machine, I start the command prompt and use dsregcmd /status. The machine is Azure AD Joined.
Also, the SSO State shows that PRT isn't available meaning that the password might be expired, but I just created the account and its the same issue with all other accounts so I don't think this is causing the issue:
(https://i.sstatic.net/XIqfSQ3c.png)
